# Graphics32: resize a lot of images

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, graphics32

3/24/2016 
I am 76 and when I wrote that I thought it made sense, but like everyone else I am not sure what I was asking. Here's what I have cobbled together (it ain't pretty)  from scouring the Internet. It *almost* works, the only thing missing is preserving the Aspect ratio. It is making tall pics look fat. In 40-years of programming I have probably had two hours total, of coding graphics stuff. :)

```
procedure TfrmTools.Shrink(aFn : String; Wid,Ht : Integer);
var
  Bmp : TBitmap;    // These three are created
  Jpg : TJpegImage; //  and Freed globally
  Dst : TBitmap32;  //  to save some bit-thrashing
begin
  try
    Src.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(aFn);  // Src = TImage32
    Dst:=TBitmap32.Create;
    Dst.SetSize(Wid,Ht);
    Src.Bitmap.DrawTo(Dst,Dst.BoundsRect);
    bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
    jpg:=TJPEGImage.Create;
    bmp.Assign(Dst);
    jpg.Assign(bmp);
    jpg.SaveToFile('D:\Test1280x720.jpg');  // Just testing
  finally
    Bmp.Free;  // As above
    Jpg.Free;  // As above
    Dst.Free;  // As above
  end;
end;
```

3/23/2016 
I took advice from a good soul here and bit the bullet with Graphis32 and glad I did, but have hit a wall. I have Paths to about 1200 images in a database and all is going well for displaying, saving etc.

Some of the images are between 6 and 9MB and do not need to be stored that big as they will only ever be viewed on a PC screen. I want to reduce them to a desired size, say, 1920 x 1080 and retain H x W ratio. I do not want to reduce images if they are already smaller than 1920 x 1080.

I have done a lot of searching and trial and error and so far only error. I have the Saving-part after scaling and/or rotation when the user is working working manually. But I want to be able to scan through the entire Database and change sizes on the fly.

A code snippet would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to iterate through a list of filenames and perform your resizing code on each. As a simple start...

```
function TForm1.ResizeImage(const Filename: String): String;
begin
  Result:= '';
  try

    //Your resizing code here

  except
    on e: Exception do begin
      Result:= e.Message;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ResizeAllImages(const List: TStringList);
var
  X: Integer;
  R: String;
begin
  for X := 0 to List.Count - 1 do begin
    R:= ResizeImage(List[X]);
    if R <> '' then begin
      //Report error in a memo control
      Memo1.Lines.Add(List[X]);
      Memo1.Lines.Add(R);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Load a list of filenames into a `TStringList` and then call `ResizeAllImages` passing in this string list. It's a good idea to report exceptions too, therefore I also included very simple error reporting. You'll definitely want to expand on this though, for example implementing a progress bar.

If this is for a production environment, for example something you intend to distribute or even sell, you would want to consider using a separate thread for such tasks.

I would also highly advise not to overwrite the existing images, just in case. Implement some sort of output directory, and save the newly resized images there.

Comment: There is also good practice to load image header at first, it contains width and height so it's possible to decide is it needed to load this image at all or we can immediately move to next one.

Comment: @YuriyAfanasenkov I don't doubt it, but according to the question, OP already knows how to do the re-sizing, just needed to know how to do it in bulk for 1,200 images. That would be a different question.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on your edit marked `3/24/2016` where you say that the remaining problem is the missing aspect ratio when you resize large images. Assuming the two arguments `Wid, Ht: integer` are the maximum width and height to apply I suggest the following changes marked with comments:

```
procedure TfrmTools.Shrink(aFn : String; Wid,Ht : Integer);
var
  Bmp : TBitmap;    // These three are created
  Jpg : TJpegImage; //  and Freed globally
  Dst : TBitmap32;  //  to save some bit-thrashing
  DstWidth, DstHeight: integer; // Add
  AspRatio: single;             // Add
begin
  Bmp := nil;  // not related to your question, see comment in text
  Jpg := nil;  // -"-
  Dst := nil;  // -"-
  try
    Src.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(aFn);  // Src = TImage32

  // Add following lines
  DstWidth := Src.Width;
  DstHeight := Src.Height;
  AspRatio := Src.Width/Src.Height;

  if (DstWidth > Wid) then
  begin
    DstWidth := Wid;
    DstHeight := round(DstWidth / AspRatio);
  end;

  if (DstHeight > Ht) then
  begin
    DstHeight := Ht;
    DstWidth := round(DstHeight * AspRatio);
  end;
  // end of added lines

    Dst:=TBitmap32.Create;
//    Dst.SetSize(Wid,Ht); // Replace parameters
    Dst.SetSize(DstWidth,DstHeight);
    Src.Bitmap.DrawTo(Dst,Dst.BoundsRect);
    bmp:=TBitmap.Create;
    jpg:=TJPEGImage.Create;
    bmp.Assign(Dst);
    jpg.Assign(bmp);
    jpg.SaveToFile('D:\Test1280x720.jpg');  // Just testing
  finally
    Bmp.Free;  // As above
    Jpg.Free;  // As above
    Dst.Free;  // As above
  end;
end;
```

The `Bmp`, `Jpg` and `Dst` variables need to be nilled before `try` to prevent eventual calls to `Free` with uninitialized memory references. This could happen if any code, before all three objects are created, raises an exception.